# Avoid printing identical output

Tags: python

I am making a troubleshooting program, which will ask the user for an input, search through some lists to find the problem and give them a solution.

```
f=open('problem.txt')
lines=f.readlines()

problem1 = ["cracked", "phone", "screen", "dropped"]
problem2 = ["charging", "port", "phone"]
problem3 = ["slow", "phone", "freeze"]

problem_input = input ("What is your problem? ")
list_split = (problem_input.split( ))

for i in problem1:
    if i in list_split:
        print (lines[0])


for i in problem2:
    if i in list_split:
        print (lines[1])
```

But if i input, `"my phone is cracked"`, the output will be printed twice. How do I only print this once?

Comment: It prints it twice since it matches with both the first loop and the second loop. You can implement an AND condition logic or by using break

Answer (score 1):

You're cycling through a list of problem cases and your input matches twice. The matches are `"phone"` and `"cracked"`. To prevent that, stop at the first match like that:

```
for i in problem1:
    if i in list_split:
        print (lines[0])
        break
```

The `break` keyword will quit the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through your "problems" lists and getting multiple matches for your condition.

You could `return` your matched problem by making this into a function:

```
f=open('problem.txt')
lines=f.readlines()

problem1 = ["cracked", "screen", "dropped"]
problem2 = ["charging", "port"]
problem3 = ["slow", "freeze"]
problems = [problem1, problem2, problem3]

def troubleshoot():
    problem_input = input("What is your problem? ")
    list_split = (problem_input.split())
    for idx, problem in enumerate(problems, 1):
        if any(i in problem for i in list_split):
            return "problem{}".format(idx)
            # or return lines[0]
```

It would run as the following:

```
>>> troubleshoot()
What is your problem? my phone is slow and freezing up
'problem3'
>>> troubleshoot()
What is your problem? my phone is not charging
'problem2'
>>> 
>>> troubleshoot()
What is your problem? my phone dropped and the screen is cracked
'problem1'
```

Alternatively, if there isn't a reason for having `"phone"` in each of the `problem` lists, you might be better off using a `dict` here:

```
problems = {'cracked':1, 'screen':1, 'dropped':1,
            'charging':2, 'port':2,
            'slow':3, 'freeze':3}

user_problems = {problems[i] for i in problem_input.split()}
```

**Note:** I removed `"phone"` from both of these because it matches for every list